# Generating pdf for chisquared in R

Tags: r, dataframe, chi-squared

I want a visualize the pdf of chisquare distribution in R. I am okay with the plotting part, but it is difficult to get the dataframes. 
What I want is a pdf of 100,000 random numbers having degrees of freedom 1,2,3,6.

This is what I have tried.

```
set.seed(1)
data.frame(chisq = 0:100000) 
df1 = dchisq(x = chisq, df = 1)
df2 = dchisq(x = chisq, df = 2)
df3 = dchisq(x = chisq, df = 3)
df6 = dchisq(x = chisq, df = 6)
```

and then I get an error:

> Error in dchisq(x = chisq, df = 1): Non-numeric argument to
>   mathematical function
>
> Traceback:
>   1. dchisq(x = chisq, df = 1)

Comment: Do you want a data.frame with each column being the `dchisq` values for df = 1, 2, 3, 6?

Comment: I want 4 separate dataframes and 4 graphs for each. Graph part can be done. Need help with dataframes

Comment: I've provided an answer below, check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you need 4 different dataframes, you can avoid using the first two lines of your code and use this code

```
x = 0:99999   # this way the vector has length 100000 instead of 100001
df1 = data.frame(x = x, dchisq = dchisq(x, df = 1))
df2 = data.frame(x = x, dchisq = dchisq(x, df = 2))
df3 = data.frame(x = x, dchisq = dchisq(x, df = 3))
df6 = data.frame(x = x, dchisq = dchisq(x, df = 6))
```

---

#### EDIT

Code after discussion in the comments

```
ggplot(df1) +
  aes(x = x, y = dchisq) +
  geom_area(fill = "blue")
```

Comment: I have tried this. When i get the graph for df1 using **ggplot(df1,aes(x=X,y=..density..)) + geom_density(fill='blue')**  
But I do not get the required graph. And for df1, the numbers look abnormal

Comment: @user11607046 If you plot the graph with `x` ranging from 0 to 99999 you will get almost everything as a flat line around zero.. Try using smaller x range, for instance 0:49 or 0:99. Also, I edited my answer with the code for plotting the pdf.